# elegant way of counting items in a list by enum value in python

Tags: python, enums

I have a list of objects where every object contains a type which is an IntEnum value.
**I'm looking for an elegant way to count the number of objects in my list by their type(IntEnum) value.**

Below is a fully functioning snippet of what I came up with but it seems clunky to me. For instance adding a new type to my enum would require manual modification to other parts of the code.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from enum import IntEnum, unique
from random import randint
from textwrap import dedent
from collections import Counter

@unique
class ObjType(IntEnum):
    OT_START = 0
    OBJTYPE_0 = 1
    OBJTYPE_1 = 2
    OBJTYPE_2 = 3
    OT_END = 4
    # many more types...

@dataclass
class ObjListAttributes:
    OBJTYPE_0_count = 0
    OBJTYPE_1_count = 0
    OBJTYPE_2_count = 0

@dataclass
class ObjClass:
    t: ObjType
    attr_1: int = 0
    attr_2: float = 0
    # many more attributes...

# create list of objects with random types
objList = [ObjClass(randint(ObjType.OT_START + 1, ObjType.OT_END - 1)) for x in range(100)]

# count number of objects in list by type **THIS IS THE CLUNKY PART**
listAttrs = ObjListAttributes()
for x in objList:
    if x.t == ObjType.OBJTYPE_0:
        listAttrs.OBJTYPE_0_count += 1
    elif x.t == ObjType.OBJTYPE_1:
        listAttrs.OBJTYPE_1_count += 1
    elif x.t == ObjType.OBJTYPE_2:
        listAttrs.OBJTYPE_2_count += 1

print(dedent(f'''\
    list contains:
        {listAttrs.OBJTYPE_0_count} {ObjType.OBJTYPE_0.name} objects
        {listAttrs.OBJTYPE_1_count} {ObjType.OBJTYPE_1.name} objects
        {listAttrs.OBJTYPE_2_count} {ObjType.OBJTYPE_2.name} objects
    '''))
```

To give you some context, the snippet is part of some code that unpacks and analyzes binary data that was generated in C code. Therefore, using enums felt natural for solving the problem. I'm open to using other data structures if they result in more elegant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). But beware using it requires hashable dict keys so you can't just use the class object.

```
from collections import Counter

c= Counter(map(lambda x:x.t,objList))  # it should be x.t.value if t is an intEnum
```

Comment: Nice; that will work around the lack of a `key` parameter. It does lose the actual instances of `OjbClass` though.

Comment: Note that OP has imported `collections.Counter` already in their code, just not used it (presumably because they ran into the hashability issue).

Comment: Map doesn't modify the original list right? So he still has his instances?

Comment: `objList` will be there; the challenge is to match them to the `c`. Which is perhaps fairly straightforward, although `objList` can't be turned into a dict with counts for values and `ObjClass` instanes to match `c`.

Comment: It's ugly but if absolutely necessay you could build a dict like k: hash(ObjType) or Value : (count : int ,list[ObjClass])

Comment: I had a hunch that Counter was the right tool but as @9769953 suspected I couldn't get past the hashability issue. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Stylistically, map+lambda would be better written as a generator: Counter(x.t for x in objList).  Might be faster too.

Answer (score 1):

A bit hacky, but you could implement a `__hash__` method to your `ObjClass` class that just uses `t`:

```
@dataclass
class ObjClass:
    t: ObjType
    attr_1: int = 0
    attr_2: float = 0
    # many more attributes...

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.t)
```

Then,

```
counter = Counter(objList)
```

will work.

Afterwards, you can reset the `__hash__` method for the `ObjClass`:

```
ObjClass.__hash__ = None
```

---

It is perhaps unfortunate that `Counter` doesn't have a `key` parameter as for `sort` and the like. Then again, since `ObjClass` isn't hashable, its instances can't function as a key for a `Counter` instance (or any dict) either, so it wouldn't help in this case.

Comment: "unfortunate that Counter doesn't have a key ": The source code is in python, it should be fairly easy to add it if you wish. github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/collections/__init__.py

Comment: Couln't find anything on this so I created an issue: https://bugs.python.org/issue45338

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect my question leading to this!

Comment: Well apparently there was a PEP addressing key transforming dictionaries that was rejected: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0455/